# tomcat 8 problem not displaying any error for debug

Tags: java, tomcat

Im using tomcat 8.5.49, my logging.properties look like below:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 90
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 90
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.bufferSize = 16384
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 90
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding = UTF-8

############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = \
   2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = \
   3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE
```

i started the tomcat using following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/home/myuser/jdk1.8.0_221
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CATALINA_HOME=/home/myuser/tomcat-8.5
export CATALINA_LOG=/home/myuser/tomcat-8.5/logs
export CATALINA_OUT=$CATALINA_LOG
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms256m -Xmx512m  -Xss256k -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"
#export CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms3840m -Xmx5120m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xss256k -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"
export CATALINA_BASE=$CATALINA_HOME
$CATALINA_BASE/bin/startup.sh
date >> /home/myuser/tomcat-8.5/logs/startlog.log
```

on my jsp i do have something like this:

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*, java.lang.*"%>

    <%
      try{
         //some code
      }catch(Exception e){
         out.println("<div id=\"error\">");
         e.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out));
        out.println("</div>");
      }
    %>
```

on the JSP i run, it showing:

**HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error**

but i cannot find any error log to debug at logs/catalina.out

please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also check logs/localhost.log?  Occasionally some tomcat errors will show up in the localhost log but not catalina log.